# Display formula based on screen values in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, screen-flow

I'm working on the flow and I'm trying to display something based on data User already field on the same screen.
In my case, I have two input fields - Start Date and Period (in months). After User fill Start Date and Period, End Date should be calculated and displayed - I want effect as is shown in attached pic,.
[image: Screen Flow]
What I already did:

- create formula field "endDate" = ADDMONTHS({!startDate},{!period})
- put display field on the screen and in text I used this formula,

but it doesn't work. I think formula is not calculated until User clicks Next.

Is there any way to display this "End Date" right after User fill other values?

Comment: You can create a formula field on Flow, Find New Resource in Toolbox | Manager | New Resource. Select "Formula" in Resource Type, give a name and choose "Date" as Data Type and you can add months to your Start Date in that formula resource.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar - this doesn't answer the OP - the issue is how to get a formula to display on a screen page without clicking NEXT (that is, a dynamically refreshed screen element based on user entry in other fields)

Comment: https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/flow-reactive-screen-components-beta-learn-moar-summer-23

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom component (in Aura or LWC) having these two fields and display the calculated answer.
Place this component in the flow.